# how do i tell process.php to hold the value till the next `POST` of the `name=newurl` value deliver by form.. FORM POST UPDATE IFRAME URL SRC

Tags: php, html, post, iframe, src

the `form1.php` code works to pass the url submited on the form `POST` to update the `iframe src` of `iframe.php` from an adminside, but `process.php` is not keeping the last value posted . When the page `iframe.php` is requested again for the viewers whitout sending a form(beacuse they can't change the url feeded), returns the default src not the last posted form by the admin.

how do i tell process.php to hold the value till the next `POST` of the `name=newurl` value deliver by form.

I made a form `form1.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="newurl" action="iframe.php" method="post">
        <label for="newurl">Type the new Url</label><br>
        <input type="url" id="newurl" name="newurl">
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Go!</button><br>
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

to update the src of an Iframe by retrieving the value from `$newurl=$_POST['newurl'];`

then the iframe code `iframe.php`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div><p>Click on the blue screen</p></div>
    <div id="content">
        <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="<?php require_once 'process.php' ?>" name="content_frame">
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the `process.php`

```
<?php 


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $newurl=$_POST['newurl'];
    echo $newurl ;
}

?>
```

Comment: TYPO: `;` missing after the `include` in `iframe.php`

Comment: You can't keep `$_POST` data. It's gone when the script ends. So you have to save the value somwhere, either in a file or a database. When admin makes make new url (lets say iframe16.php), save this. When user comes along, read the value from file/db and present the url.

Answer (score 0):

There are two mainstream practices.

1. Save the post value to session.
   **Notice**: You must session start when you try to read or write $_SESSION, and you can't start repeated or you'll get a warning.

```php
// form1.php
session_start();
$_SESSION["newurl"] = $_POST["newurl"];
```

```php
// process.php
session_start();
$newurl = $_SESSION["newurl"]
echo $newurl;
```

2. Save the post value to database. (skip example)

---

#### Other

If your `iframe` is contain in `form1.php`, you can also use AJAX to achieve your goals, and you even no need save the post value to session or database.

For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form name="newurl" action="iframe.php" method="post">
      <label for="newurl">Type the new Url</label><br>
      <input type="url" id="newurl" name="newurl">
      <button id="submitButton" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Go!</button><br>
    </form>

    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="" name="content_frame"></iframe>

    <script>
      function alterSubmit(event) {
        // prevent default submit 
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();

        let newurl = document.querySelector("#newurl").value;
        let iframe = document.querySelector("iframe");

        let fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("submit", "");
        fd.append("newurl", newurl);

        fetch("/path/to/process.php", {
          method: "POST",
          body: fd
        }).then(
          r => r.text()
        ).then(r => {
          // change iframe src   
          iframe.src = r;
        });
      }

      document.querySelector("#submitButton").onclick = e => {
        alterSubmit(e);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```php
// process.php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $newurl=$_POST['newurl'];
    echo $newurl ;
}
```